# View is not visible after alpha(0) animation

Tags: android

I need to fadeout a view and I need to show it again after some user action.

So I did this :

```
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(duration).start();
```

on animation end I did :

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and then when I want to show it once again I do

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

after which the view is not visible for some reason.

currently the only way I found to solve this issue is by doing this on animation end :

```
view.animate().alpha(1).start();
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and this solves it.
Wanted to know if there's other way which is more elegant and a better practice.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reset the alpha back to 1: `view.setAlpha(1f)` when showing your view again.

Comment: This works!
Turns out that only checking the (Deprecated)setAlpha(int) and assuming that if this don't work , setAlpha(float) also won't work was wrong approach.
Thanks